# What is commonly used to remove noise and smooth grayscale images?

Tags: image, image-processing

I know at least three ways to do it :

1. Averaging filter, followed by thresholding
2. Median Filter, followed by thresholding
3. Thresholding followed by opening or closing

I understand why they work, but what is commonly used, and what are the pros/cons of each ?

Answer (score 0):

the use is dependent on your image:

1. averaging filter: widens edges  (blurs), used as a low pass filter with only mathematic actions, the down side here is that somtimes you want to keep your edges and average elsewhere, this also creates values that did not exist in the original image.
2. Median Filter: keeps original image values integrity, very good for salt and pepper noise, sometimes you specifically want to smooth edges and this can be problematic with this filter, 
   Median Filter is done with sorting and therefor cost more processing time then averaging.

you should look at Bilateral Filtering, this is a very good solution for many applications.

good luck.